# Unexpected T_STRING in if clause with spaces

Tags: php

My problem is the following: To keep order in my scripts, I always put lots of spaces in my if-statements, like this:

```
if( ! isset( $_GET['user'] ) || ! isset( $_GET['user'] ) )
   ...
```

From time to time, though everything seems correct, this produces errors like "Unexpected T_STRING..." etc. Then I change the line to:

```
if(!isset($_GET['user'])||!isset($_GET['user']))
   ...
```

save the file, re-insert the spaces, save the file again and everything works fine. Any ideas what could cause this? Is it maybe a bug of the PHP parser?

(It's not specifically this statement, it happens with many such spaces-including statements)

Edit: I just managed to revert the file to when it didn't work, this is the exact code that produces the error:

```
if(! isset( $_GET['user'] ) || ! isset( $_GET['parent'] ) )
```

I also changed every character in sequence, it seems to be the space between `||` and `!`.

The error message says:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ')' in ...
```

You can download the file here: http://geardev.de/test.zip

Comment: Both of these lines are valid; whitespace doesn't affect anything in this regard.  What do you mean by "from time to time"?

Comment: That's exactly the problem - Both lines are valid and the whitespace SHOULD not affect anything. But it does. I couldn't determine a pattern by now, it seems to occur randomly.

Comment: Can you show us an example of a line of code that produces this?

Comment: As well as the exact error message? i.e. what was the parser expecting when it encountered an unexpected T_STRING

Comment: The code above produced an error until I removed and re-inserted the spaces. The message is: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ')' in ...`

Comment: to find the cause we need further information, a context. What you do before that?

Comment: I would say post the entire page's code (the error could be elsewhere and the line error not right), or if you have any process which could be modifying the file. You could start with a clean file, copy the code into that file, and delete or move the problem file. I suspect there's a problem higher up or lower down than the obvious one here.

Comment: I pasted the version of the line not working to a completely blank file, now I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!' in ...`

Comment: We're literally guessing. Your error above, at the bottom of the question, makes it look as if you are calling a function (hence the `,` part), so my guess is the file is not getting parsed correctly. Why? Without having access *to the actual file with the real problem*, more guessing will ensue. Surely, PHP is not always right when it points to a line.

Comment: Whitespace and whitespace are different things. If you / your editor inserts a nbsp or other Unicode whitespace, PHP will see it as T_STRING. Else you are mistaken about the actual error location. CV as Too localized.

Comment: I uploaded the file for you. http://geardev.de/test.zip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a character-encoding problem. I'm not sure the exact character encoding that you're using that is causing this, but when you open up the PHP file using a hex editor, the space character you've correctly identified as causing this is actually a multi-byte character `\xC2` & `\xA0`. All other space characters are `\x20` as they should be:
[image]

---

**Edit:**
`\xC2A0` is the UTF-8 way of encoding `U+00A0` ([non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)). This could have come from copying-and-pasting from a browser, a PDF, or an advanced text editor, or maybe your keyboard has <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> mapped to NBSP.

There have been complaints by people of Netbeans inserting NBSP randomly into their code, but I suspect this is due to the user accidentally holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> when typing the space.

Comment: Strange, but where does this come from? Do you know a key combination that produces this character? It looks like a space in Netbeans, though.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible answer to this, is that you're simply mistaken.

Sorry :) the issue is somewhere between keyboard and chair. Now if you can come up with a reproducible error, I take it all back.

Comment: The problem is that it is not reproducible, it just happens absolutely by random.